# Почему лента новостей не обновляется с EventSource?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Мне нужно обновлять ленту новостей без использования `ajax` в `setInterval`.

Одно из решений как я понял это `EventSource`, но проблема в том что браузер все равно с задержкой посылает `GET` запросы на сервер, эта задержка контролируется полем `retry`.

Вопрос в том, можно ли не посылая эти бестолковые запросы на сервер, обновлять ленту в браузере только при вызове скрипта `news.php`? Иначе эта технология ничем не отличается от обычного `setInterval`

`news.php`:

```php
header("Cache-Control: no-store");
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream");

echo "event: update\n";
echo "data: news\n";
echo "retry: 2000\n";
echo "\n\n";
```

`news.js`:

```js
const eventSource = new EventSource("news.php");
```

В результате каждые 2 секунды посылается `GET` запрос, что выглядит крайне тупо. Хотелось бы не посылая запросов обновлять ленту.

Comment: Если ваша страница не будет посылать запросов на сервер, то откуда она узнает что новости изменились?

Comment: например как при использовании сокета, там вроде браузер ничего не посылает

Comment: может заголовка какого не хватает или еще чего?)

Comment: @newman Можете прочитать про SSE, это по своей сути однонаправленный сокет с сервера на клиент с перманентным подключением. Т.е. в действительности, запрос на сервер придет всего один раз и установит соединение, а делее, может ожидать от сервера сообщений.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Какой-то другой код на у вас запрашивает сервер, т.к. в самой банальной реализации, никаких запросов нет. Попробуйте сделать так и проверить, а далее, доработать свою реализацию.

Серверный код (index.php):

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);

header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Connection: keep-alive');
header('Cache-Control: no-store');

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

$messageCounter = 1;

while (true) {
    if (connection_aborted()) break;
    
    echo 'data: ' . $messageCounter++ . '. Message from bigboxcode, at - ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    echo "\n\n";
    
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    
    sleep(3);
}
```

Клиентский код (index.html):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>PHP SSE Demo</title>
</head>

<body>
<ul id="list">
    <!-- new content appears here -->
</ul>
</body>

<script>
    const eventSource = new EventSource('http://localhost:8001');

    eventSource.onmessage = function (currentEvent) {
        const listElement = document.getElementById('list');
        const newElement = document.createElement('li');
        newElement.innerText = currentEvent.data;

        listElement.appendChild(newElement)
    };
</script>
</html>
```

Далее, `php -S localhost:8001` в директории с php файлом и в браузере откройте index.html, как разультат, должна бытьь чистая вкладка network.

Comment: да, вкладка нетворк правда чиста, но если убрать цикл, то результат получается тот же, и браузер продолжает опрашивать сервер, я так понимаю все дело в цикле

Comment: мы просто имеем постоянн запущенный php скрипт

Comment: так получается?

Comment: Браузер не опрашивает, он пытается установить перманентное подклчюение к серверу, т.к. EventSource это предполагает и да, по виду получается, что запросы с клиента идут каждую секунду (важно понимать, что это попытка reconnect-a, а не чистого вида long-polling).

Comment: Можно избавиться от цикла и использовать sub/pub от redis, там могу предположить все на генераторах. Но должен сказать, что по факту, вы получите тот же самый бесконечный цикл, только уже под копотом consumer-a.

Comment: @martinUeer чтобы держать постоянное подключение, ваш скрипт прежде всего - должен работать, а вы пытаетесь запустить несколько разных процессов и чтобы клиент вас вечно слушал, но это невозможно, т.к. соединение разрывается после того, как ваш скрипт отработал, соответственно, браузер начинает опрашивать сервер, когда тот оживет и опять установит с ним некий stream.